# Is it wrong to use Pipe symbol (|) in a json key?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a object something like:

```
{
    "category|subCategory" : value
}
```

Is it wrong to use "|" (which I intend to use as a delimiter) in key of an object?

Comment: It is neither "right" nor "wrong". It is *valid*, and that's all that really matters

Comment: Yes it's valid. But you won't be able to access the object property by dot notation.

Comment: Yes, I am using the property using ["category|subCategory"], so thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Separator characters are normally chosen from the set of characters that are not already being used. Pipe is often a good character for this in many data sets. Looking at common Redis use, which uses this paradigm a lot to form composite keys, the pipe char and the colon appear most often. Colon is very popular for this purpose as it has a similar language meaning but it's only usable if you're sure you won't find colon appearing as valid characters in the individual keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is valid. Property names may be any string.

Wrongness seems like a moral judgement that is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), any `string` can be used as the key.

> A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022). All code points may
>   be placed within the quotation marks except for the code points that must be escaped: quotation mark
>   (U+0022), reverse solidus (U+005C), and the control characters U+0000 to U+001F.

Even `{"⛄|⛱|☠": "is valid"}` is valid.